# How to select custom layout to use in Apache POI

Tags: apache-poi

I have a pptx with following slide layouts:

```
System.out.println("Available slide layouts:");
    for(XSLFSlideMaster master : ppt.getSlideMasters()){
    for(XSLFSlideLayout layout : master.getSlideLayouts()){
    System.out.println("Name: "+layout.getName()+" Type: "+layout.getType());

    Available slide layouts:
Name: Content Type: OBJ_ONLY
Name: Title and 4 Content Type: FOUR_OBJ
Name: Title Only Type: TITLE_ONLY
Name: DETAIL_SCORECARD Type: CUST
Name: Scorecard Type: CUST
Name: CSCLayout1 Type: CUST
Name: 1_Blank Type: BLANK
Name: Title, Content, and 2 Content Type: OBJ_AND_TWO_OBJ
Name: Title and Content Type: TITLE_AND_CONTENT
Name: Title, Text, and Content Type: TX_AND_OBJ
Name: Two Content Type: TWO_OBJ
Name: Main Type: TITLE
```

How do I go about selecting 2nd or 3rd CUST layout option

Current implementation works fine with 1st CUST slide layout

```
FileInputStream input = null;
        input = new FileInputStream(filename);
        slideshow = new XMLSlideShow(input);
XSLFSlideMaster defaultMaster = slideshow.getSlideMasters()[0];
    XSLFSlideLayout detailedscorecard = defaultMaster.getLayout(SlideLayout.CUST);
```

I've tried renaming the slide name within slide  master, but it doesn't seem to have any affect on the above list. is there a way to use layout.getName() to find the actual name of the slide layout,

```
XSLFSlideLayout detailedscorecard = defaultMaster.getLayout(SlideLayout.CUST);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ok.. got an answer from a friend and got it resolved...

```
XSLFSlideLayout detailedscorecard = null;
for (XSLFSlideMaster master : slideshow.getSlideMasters()){
  for (XSLFSlideLayout layout1 : master.getSlideLayouts()){
    if (layout1.getName().equals("Scorecard")) {
        detailedscorecard=layout1;
    }
  }
 }
```